# How to count the number of times a value occurs in each column (per column), using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there anyway to use pandas to count the number of times that a certain value occurs in each column?

> data = pd.DataFrame({'userID':['Luis', 'Mike', 'Harvey'],
>   'category1':[True, False, True], 'category2': [True, True, False],
>   'category3':[False, False, False]})

Let's say I want to count the number of 'True' boolean per category to get a return of:

```
 Category 1  -- Category 2 -- Category 3
      2             2              0
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count occurence by `sum` of boolean mask - `True` values are processes like `1`s:

```
#count all columns without first to Series
print (data.iloc[:, 1:].sum().astype(int))

category1    2
category2    2
category3    0
dtype: int32

#or to one row DataFrame
df = data.iloc[:, 1:].sum().astype(int).to_frame().T
```

General solution with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`):

```
val = True
df = data.iloc[:, 1:].eq(val).sum().astype(int).to_frame().T
print (df)

   category1  category2  category3
0          2          2          0
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  In fact, the first way is better to get it listed downwards instead - cheers!

Comment: @halfer - Thank you, 2 typos :)

Answer (score 0):

`a = dict(df.category1.value_counts())`
This gives you output like {True : 20, False : 15}